# How to select just BirthYear from DOB in VB.net from SQL Server 2008 database

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, sql-server-2008

I have a `DOB` column in a table that is currently in use. See below.

[image: Database DOB column]

I want to select just the Year from that `DOB` and display that on a Listbox (or any appropriate interface on a page). We are not using SPs. So I will probably coding SQL directly from the page or using SQL datasource. Using LINQ is alright if that can be done in it.

So please someone suggests me how this can be done.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Here are two links: [How to populate a ComboBox using SqlDataReader](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vbgeneral/thread/6967b0b9-8c09-4789-857e-96924f1ec064)? [Filling listbox with datareader](http://vbcity.com/forums/t/55977.aspx) Change the query as suggested by others above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT Year(DateOfBirth) AS Year FROM MyTable ORDER BY Year
```

By including the DISTINCT keyword you will prevent duplicates in your list and by adding the ORDER BY clause the years will be sorted ascending. You can then bind the result to your listbox.

Answer (score 4):

Use the [`YEAR`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186313.aspx) function in your SQL statement.

```
SELECT YEAR([DateOfBirth])
  FROM MyTable
```

Answer (score 1):

In your TSQL, write this:

```
SELECT YEAR(DateOfBirth), ...
FROM ...
```